# Hash Table linked list?

Tags: c++

I have some questions on an old homework assignment. I was hoping I could get some help with this one. What I am supposed to do is read from a .txt file, and insert words from that text file into an array of linked list, then hash each word and print the output, and how many collisions it has.
So far, what I got it to do is to read from the text file and insert it into the linked list, but I don't know how to write a hash function with a key to hash the words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Hash {
    int collisions = 0;
    struct HashWords
    {
        string words;
        struct HashWords* next;
    };
    HashWords* head;
public:
    Hash() :collisions(0){ head = NULL; }
    void Load_Dictionary();
    void appendNode(string);
};

void Hash::Load_Dictionary() {
    string words;
    fstream in("dictionary.txt", ios::in);
    while (in >> words)
    {
        cout << "Word: " << words << endl;
        appendNode(words);
    }
    in.close();
}
void Hash::appendNode(string word)
{
    HashWords* newNode, *nodePtr;
    newNode = new HashWords;
    newNode->words = word;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    else
    {
        nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Hash dictionary;
    dictionary.Load_Dictionary();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After the words are loaded from the .txt file and inserted into the linked list, it is then displayed:

[image: output image]

What I need to do next is to create a key and hash function to hash those words and print the result, and how many collision it has. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: What have you tried that relates *to the hashing specifically*? It's both a broad and a widely covered topic. What are you expecting to get in an answer that you can't find when you type "how to build a string hashmap" into Google?

Comment: You need to read some more on hash tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table . HashTable is a table of linked lists in the simplest implementation. You only have one linked list. Each word is appended to the corresponding linked list on the table depending on its hash

Comment: I understand the concept, that's not hard. It's the actual coding that I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Simplest way would be to go with separate chaining, like `vector<list<Entry> > map;` and `void insert(Entry entry){ map[hash_function(entry)].append(entry);}`. If you use a one-dimensional structure for storage (which is a valid basis), you would not use a list but something array-like (std::vector or std::array) because you need quick access by index (without collision, an insert should be in O(1)). But let's start with you deciding for a hash function and a collision resolution method in particular.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed a few points.

You should have an array of linked lists, not just one linked list.
That is, every array element is a linked list.
(It's a good idea to write a separate linked list class, or use `std::list`.)

This array of lists is your hash table.

The word you're storing is the key.
You use the hash function to calculate which "bucket" (array index) the word belongs in.

The number of collisions for each bucket is the length of the list in that bucket.